# Using Groovy in Confluence

Tags: mysql, macros, groovy, confluence

I'm new to Groovy and coding in general, but I've come a long way in a very short amount of time. I'm currently working in Confluence to create a tracking tool, which connects to a MySql Database. We've had some great success with this, but have hit a wall with using Groovy and the Run Macro.

Currently, we can use Groovy to populate fields within the Run Macro, which really works well for drop down options, example:

```
{groovy:output=wiki}
import com.atlassian.renderer.v2.RenderMode
def renderMode = RenderMode.suppress(RenderMode.F_FIRST_PARA)
def getSql = "select * from table where x = y"
def getMacro = '{sql-query:datasource=testdb|table=false} ${getSql} {sql-query}"
def get = subRenderer.render(getMacro, context, renderMode)

def runMacro = """
{run:id=test|autorun=false|replace=name::Name, type::Type:select::${get}|keepRequestParameters = true}
{sql:datasource=testdb|table=false|p1=\$name|p2=\$type}
insert into table1 (name, type) values (?, ?)
{sql}
{run}
"""
out.println runMacro
{groovy}
```

We've also been able to use Groovy within the Run Macro, example:
`enter code here`

```
{run:id=test|autorun=false|replace=name::Name, type::Type:select::${get}|keepRequestParameters = true}
{groovy}
def checkSql = "{select * from table where name = '\name' and type = '\$type'}"
def checkMacro = "{sql-query:datasource=testdb|table=false} ${checkSql} {sql-query}"
def check = subRenderer.render(checkMacro, context, renderMode)       
if (check == "")
        {
               println("This information does not exist.")
         } else {
               println(checkMacro)
        }
{groovy}
{run}
```

However, we can't seem to get both scenarios to work together, Groovy inside of a Run Macro inside of Groovy.

We need to be able to get the variables out of the Run Macro form so that we can perform other functions, like checking the DB for duplicates before inserting data.

My first thought is to bypass the Run Macro and create a simple from in groovy, but I haven't been too lucky with finding good examples. Can anyone help steer me in the right direction for creating a simple form in Groovy that would replace the Run Macro? Or have suggestions on how to get the rendered variables out of the Run Macro?